# Clearing ObservableCollection and re-adding ViewModels throws exception

Tags: c#, wpf

So I've reached my frustration point with WPF. Please don't critique the non-clean code. I haven't refactored it yet as I do not have a working solution. My issue is that I'm trying to clear an `ObservableCollection<T>` and then reload from the service (so all data is in sync). Not the most efficient, but again trying to get it working first... Anyway, the issue I'm having is that by clearing the `ObservableCollection<T>` and then re-adding the `TransactionRowViewModels` it throws the exception `added item does not appear at given index '0'`. Any ideas? How in the world can I not clear the Collection without it causing an exception?

**TransactionsViewModel**

```
public class TransactionsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<TransactionRowViewModel> Transactions { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TransactionRowViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> Accounts { get; }

    public TransactionsViewModel(Guid accountId, IAccountService accountService, ITransactionService transactionService)
    {
        _accountId = accountId;
        _transactionService = transactionService;

        TransactionRowViewModel.RowCreated += TransactionCreated;

        var accts = accountService?.GetAccounts().Select(a => new AccountViewModel { Id = a.Id, Content = a.Name });
        Accounts = new ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel>(accts);

        if (transactionService == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        LoadTransactions();
    }

    private void LoadTransactions()
    {
        var transactions = _transactionService.GetTransactions(_accountId);

        foreach (var trans in transactions)
        {
            var acct = trans.DebitAccountId;
            var val = trans.Value;

            if (trans.DebitAccountId == _accountId)
            {
                acct = trans.CreditAccountId;
                val = -1 * trans.Value;
            }

            var transVm = new TransactionRowViewModel
            {
                TransactionId = trans.TransactionId,
                Date = trans.Date,
                Account = Accounts.First(a => a.Id == acct),
                Description = trans.Description,
                Value = val,
                Balance = trans.Balance
            };

            transVm.RowUpdated += TransactionUpdated;
            Transactions.Add(transVm);
        }
    }

    private void TransactionCreated(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is TransactionRowViewModel row))
            return;

        if (row.Account == null)
                return;

        var id = _transactionService.Create(row.Date, row.Account.Id, _accountId, row.Value, row.Description);
        row.TransactionId = id;

        Transactions.Clear();
        LoadTransactions();
    }
}
```

**TransactionsRowViewModel**

```
public class TransactionRowViewModel : IEditableObject
{
    public Guid TransactionId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public AccountViewModel? Account { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; } = "";

    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public static event EventHandler? RowCreated;

    public event EventHandler? RowUpdated;

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        _editNum++;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        _editNum--;

        if (_editNum != 0) 
            return;

        if (TransactionId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            OnRowCreated();
        }
        else
        {
            OnRowUpdated();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnRowCreated()
    {
        RowCreated?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    protected virtual void OnRowUpdated()
    {
        RowUpdated?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    private int _editNum;
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Added item does not appear at given index '0'.
   at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.AdjustBefore(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.CommitNew()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.System.ComponentModel.IEditableCollectionView.CommitNew()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.CommitRowItem()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.Execute(Object parameter, IInputElement target)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.EndEdit(RoutedCommand command, DataGridCell cellContainer, DataGridEditingUnit editingUnit, Boolean exitEditMode)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.CommitAnyEdit()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnEnterKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnKeyDownThunk(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawKeyboardActions actions, Int32 scanCode, Boolean isExtendedKey, Boolean isSystemKey, Int32 virtualKey)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(MSG& msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
```

Comment: @Dennis1679 sorry, fixed. Transactions is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: I'd be checking if `RowCreated` is being invoked on a different thread to the main/UI one.

Comment: @keelerjr12 Why do you need to clear the transactions after adding a new item and then load all of them again?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I need the model to re-calculate the balances for every transaction. Since you could have added a transaction in the middle of the collection (by date). This causes a ripple-effect for every transaction to be re-calculated.

Comment: @MarkFeldman, I've added the additional code. I use events to actually make the call.

Comment: @Asti I've added the stack trace.